# php posting to DB mysql increments not working

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm currently having a problem with my DB's auto increments. ( NOTE THIS WORKED ON MY OLD HOST I'VE SINCE THEN CHANGED SERVERS AND NOW HOSTING ON A UBUNTU SERVER ). Which I'm not really sure if that makes a difference.

But here is the data that gets "INSERTED" into the DB or what should be.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_fruits VALUES ('', '$description', '$keywords', '$fruits')");
```

so the first '' should be the ID that auto increments but it doesn't.

I've tried removing the '' and leaving just the ,

I've tried totally removing the '',

Only thing I've tried and succeeded is changing it to '0', for a strange reason that worked but there are a lot of files and pages to check if that worked correctly and to edit.

Surly that's not an efficient way to resolve this anyway. I don't currently have the old hosting anymore so I can't even check on a PHP version if that was causing the problems.

Are there any query's I can run to resolve this dramatic stressful problem that's been driving me batty for hours now? I appreciate any help.

Comment: are you sure the column was already incremented in your table after migrating it?

Comment: Yes I've been through the DB and checked the column is set to auto increment

Comment: `mysqli_query("INSERT INTO table_fruits VALUES ('$description', '$keywords', '$fruits')");` have you tried something like this ?

Comment: that is also the solution that im also thinking @jerome. It might work

Comment: i think so too cause auto incremented fields does not include in insert query

Comment: Yeah i did state in the post I had tried to remove the field totally for the ID still the same issue of it not posting to the DB.

Comment: btw your mysqli_query lacks of 1 parameter  = `connection`

Comment: connection is established from a config.php file and that file is called right at the top of the code. If I didn't have a connection parameter it wouldn't have also worked on my old host which it did.

Comment: did your new host and the old one have the same cofigurations?

Comment: I'm unable to check as the old host shutdown luckily enough I had a full backup since i make them regular.

Comment: can i ask is that the only fields that the table has?

Comment: Yes thats correct.

Comment: Have you tried defining the fields like this ? `mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_fruits(description,keywords,fruits) VALUES ('$description', '$keywords', '$fruits')");`

Comment: I already define them above, but there isn't an issue with the code rather than when i switched host the auto increment stopped working none of the code has changed since the old host ( where it was working ).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can change from column settings as autoincrement. But at this point, I have encountered different problems with different versions of MySQL. So if you want to achieve the direct result in practice, export the whole table. Define autoincrement over SQL code. Run the new code.

**Note: Make sure you get a backup!**

Comment: Do you have an example? I don't fully understand what you mean much appreciated.

Comment: Login to phpMyAdmin and export the table which have problem and add autoincrement on over sql. After did that, reupload your new code to phpMyAdmin and check that.